# Get week day from date

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm building a Weather App for a project at uni. I'm trying to put the names of the week days instead of the dates.
But for some reason it only writes Thursday. I can't figure what I'm missing.

This is what I tried. I get the myDate from a weather API and I've checked and all dates are right.

```
    var myDate = objData.getString("datetime")
    var date = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(myDate)
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.time = date
    var dayNumber = cal[Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK]
    val formatter: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", currentLocale)
    val dayWeek = formatter.format(dayNumber)
    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textDay1).text = dayWeek
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) Firstly, try to use `val` instead of `var` wherever you can (avoids lot's of unintentional bugs). Secondly, you might want to set a breakpoint at `findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textDay1).text = dayWeek` and debug your app. In the debugger, you can see the values for all of your variables. What do they say?

Comment: @João Oliveira what is the value you want in the textDay1 view? Do you want 5 or 4 instead of Thursday?

Comment: @SulavTimsina no, I actually want to show basically Wednesday, Thursday and so on. I'm trying to show the forecast for the next 5 days. But all it shows is Thursday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
fun getWeekDay(dateString:String){
    val date = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).parse(dateString)
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.time = date!!
    val formatter= SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.getDefault())
    val dayWeek = formatter.format(calendar.time)
    Log.e("TAG", "getWeekDay: $dayWeek" )
}
```

Comment: Ok this works. What was my issue?

Comment: Just compare the code you will get it.